# What are some good use cases for the CALLBACK pattern/idiom?

Tags: language-agnostic, design-patterns

I don't use this pattern, maybe there are some places where it would have been appropriate and I used something else. Have you used it in your daily coding? Feel free to give samples, in your language of choice, along with your explanation.

Comment: There are several things called the "callback pattern"; please provide a brief definition so we know which one you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use callbacks pretty much every day in the following scenarios:

- Events: When the user clicks their mouse on a control, presses a key or otherwise interacts with the UI in a way I need to handle, I subscribe to the delegate that the control publishes for the event. I can then handle it by updating the UI, cancelling the event in certain circumstances or otherwise taking some special action.
- Multithreaded Programming: When programming a GUI, it's important to keep the UI responsive and indicate the progress of a long-running background event to the user. To do this, I kick off the task in a separate thread and then publish delegates (events in the .NET world) that provide my UI with the opporutinty to notify the user about progress that's happening.
- Lambda functions: In .NET, lambda functions are a form of a delegate, one that lets me interact with another piece of code's operation at a later point in time. LINQ is a great example of this. I can create a small matching function and then supply it to a LINQ query. Later, when I execute my query against a collection, the matching function is called to determine if there is a match for the query. This allows me to not have to build or worry about the query mechanism. I just have to tell the query mechanism where to go to find out if a comparison is a match or not.

These examples just scratch the surface, I'm sure. But they are useful examples of how I use callbacks every day.

Answer (score 2):

Callbacks aren't really a "pattern" - more like a building block. A number of the [gang of four design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns:_Elements_of_Reusable_Object-Oriented_Software) use virtual methods in a callback-like way. Justin Niessner has already mentioned [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Callbacks are much older than OOP (and probably older than 3GLs and even assembler). Another old idea is the parameter block - the C interpretation being a struct full of related members to be passed to a function so that function doesn't need a huge parameter list.

OOP classes build upon the parameter block (and add a philosophy to it). The class instance itself is a parameter block passed by reference to its methods. The virtual table is a dispatch-handling parameter block. Every virtual method has a callback pointer in the dispatch-handling parameter block. A pure virtual method reserves space for the callback pointer in the parameter block, and promises to provide the actual pointer later.

Since the class is the building block for object oriented design patterns, and parameter blocks and callbacks are the building blocks of classes - well, you could claim that all OOP design patterns are built from these ideas.

I'd like to be able to say "parameter blocks and callbacks, plus style rules guiding their use, inspired object orientation" but as appealing as it sounds, I don't know whether it's true.

Answer (score 1):

The .NET platform uses callbacks heavily to implement the Observer pattern.

They also get used for handling Asynchronous processes.

Answer (score 0):

Objective C and the Cocoa framework make a lot of use of it.  An example would be `NSURLConnection`, which will inform an object given to it (called its **delegate**) when something happens on the connection:

```
NSURLConnection *foo = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Note the passing of `delegate` there. The request proceeds in the background, and the instance will then send messages to the delegate (in this case, `self`), like:

```
connectionDidFinishLoading:
connection:didFailWithError:
```

You get the idea.  I believe this is called the "observer pattern".  It's all tied in to Cocoa's event loop (as far as I know, I'm still learning) and is cheap 'n easy asynchronous programming.  A lot of frameworks in a variety of languages follow this approach.

.NET has delegates as well, which are similar.  Think events.

Answer (score 0):

I use it a great deal in javascript to let me know when an asynchronous call has finished, so the result can be processed.

But, in javascript, and now in C#3, I pass in functions as a parameter, so that the processing can go on without explicitly setting up a delegate to be called.